# Hide '/admin' in URL in cakephp3

Tags: cakephp, routes, admin

I am working on admin section for a website(its has only admin section) using cakephp3. My URL ends with '/admin'.

Can I modify or route to hide '/admin' from the URL.

Comment: can you give more details? "/admin" is already simple, if you hide it, how can you access admin panels?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please elaborate your question. 
Although you can always beautify your routes using routes.php in cakephp 3 config folder .
For more details refer to this http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html

Comment: for eg: my URL is 'http://dev.pms.com/admin/users/login' but i want to show only 'http://dev.pms.com/users/login' i.e. hide '/admin' from URL. Is it possible through routes.php

Comment: You can always do that by soft linking you admin folder to your root folder (something like this ln -s {target-filename} {symbolic-filename} ) , also you can do through htaccess but through routes I am not sure you can do it.

Comment: Found the answer and for anyone looking out for it.
$routes->connect('/', ['prefix' => 'admin', 'controller' => 'YourControllerName', 'action' => 'YourActionName'']);